# where microphone captures loudly in cardioid polar pattern

Tags: cardioid

https://www.shure.eu/musicians/discover/educational/polar-patterns

[image]

From the patterns is seems the loudest part is outer circle. There is a 5db decrease with each inner circle.

Is that correct or other way around?

***Edit and follow up question:***

Is there a way to calculate the distance from microphone edge to this `0°` and `-5` db most sensitive spot?

`People give advice like talk from 6-12 inch away in front of microphone.`

Does that come from experience or any way to measure the spot?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. The labeling says 0dB at the outer circle, showing max sensitivity. Towards center are less sensitivity.

The diagram however is only an approximate depiction, intended for marketing. An actual measurement will be different, not beeing exactly as smooth. There will be small bumps and dimples in various directions. Most important though is that the measured pattern will be different depending on sound frequency. Most "conventional" cardoid mics becomes more and more omni towards lower frequencies. This is not to say that there is anything wrong with the microphones, only that the real world as always is not quite as beatiful as marketing wants to show it or that the engineering wants it to be.

Comment: Is there a way to calculate this most sensitive spot? like 6 inch or 12 from microphone edge?

Comment: It is not a distance - it is a direction. "Straight ahead" is most sensitive. Exactly where straight ahead is depends on the form of the mic. The mic will be more sensitive the closer you are.

Comment: hmm, then with `0°` what those circles mean?

Comment: The red in the diagram illustrates the sensitivity in different directions. 0° is "straight" ahead. As if you hold the microphone in your hand and try to "eat it". You have probably seen singers on stage using a mic like this. In this direction the mic most sensitive. If you turn the mic around and sing into it where the connector is, that is 180 degrees. In that direction the mic is about 30dB less sensitive if I read the diagram correctly. This is why the red diagram is at -30dB at 180 degress. The "ball" diagram on the left is only a bit of illustration.